What's the white dot on SAGA scatterplot
I'm new to SAGA. I tried making a scatterplot between 2 rasters, but in the graphic result aside from the line model, there's a white dot. What does the dot mean?
Here is the image:


Please show us the scatter plot with the white dot, so we have a clue

Here is the image link https://imgur.com/zT1Fdt

Please take the [tour] to find out how this site works and edit your question
